# Baking materials not working

Tags: materials

I need to export a model to to unity.

The issue comes with baking I need all materials in one texture file so I followed [this guys video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQMtZi9j5d0) step by step with same settings and all but it just comes out like this

(NSFW Image)

> [image]

And that's how its supposed to look like (NSFW Image)

> [image]

[image] (NSFW)

Comment: can you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I don't think posting screenshots of a nude model is a good idea, even if it's not done explicitly, reframing the screenshots and a warning for people downloading the file would be definitely better. And pro-tip for sharing files: when you do File ► Save As, the file browser have an option to compress the file. Yours gets down to 8Mb this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your materials are based on "Shader to RGB" nodes and Window texture coordinates.

[image]

This kind of materials can't be baked as is: because they change depending on the surroundings and the camera angle. The baking process makes them all constant and flat.

You need to use different methods if you want to make materials that can be baked. Or, if your goal is to render outside of Blender: make the materials in your target software, with its materials system.

Comment: I thought this could be it too but I dont know how to go about fixing it

Answer (score -1):

So I just used the original model from the creator that was meant for sfm and I have less problems with that, I still have problems with that but they should be easier to solve